# Mql4 remove icon from string

Tags: mql4

I have an alert and I am reading the string text. However sometimes the alert has a bell icon at the start.

It displays as "?? This is the alert info" I have tried `int replaceIcon = StringReplace(result[1],"?? ","");` which does not work. No error.

I have also tried `result[1] = StringTrimLeft(result[1]);`

Answer (score 0):

It works for both string and array, not clear why it does not work for you. Maybe you expect something different. Please show the full MCVE code with a problem.

```
  string msg="?? This is the alert info";
  StringReplace(msg,"?? ","");
  printf("%i %s: msg=%s.",__LINE__,__FILE__,msg);
     //32 tmp2.mq4: msg=This is the alert info.

  string array[2];
  array[0]="?? This is the alert info";
  array[1]="?? This is the alert info!!!";
  for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
  {
     StringReplace(array[i],"?? ","");
     printf("%i %s: msg=%s.",__LINE__,__FILE__,array[i]);
        // 0: 41 tmp2.mq4: msg=This is the alert info.
        // 1: 41 tmp2.mq4: msg=This is the alert info!!!.
  }
```

Comment: What I am guessing is my problem is that the bell icon is Unicode or something. When MT4 ‘printf’ it shows it as two ?? I think that is why string replace is not effective. If I pass the string like you have on the first line then that does work. I wonder is there a way to print the text raw without MT4 replacing the bell icon with ?? and then is it possible to remove it from the string. The bell icon won’t always be there.

Comment: I do not think it is possible to print raw text, unfortunately. Maybe you can try to get array of chars from the message, and then pick up and remove those exactly chars, then convert back to the string. `StringToCharArray` and `CharArrayToString` to use in that way.

Comment: I was able to extract the text and put it into raw text editor and I can see indeed the unicode characters "\ud83d\udd14 This is the alert info" This is the c++ unicode character for the bell

Comment: Then https://docs.mql4.com/en/convert/chararraytostring `CharArrayToString(array, 3)` should help I suppose.